# ChartJS - Radar chart combining same value data into one point

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, radar-chart

So, i have created a RadarChart, the problem is that it combines into a single point whenever the data value is the same, Example: [10,8,0,2.5,10,0,6.25,6.66666667,7.12418301,10] combines the two 0 values into one point.

i would like that it had individual points even if the value is the same, i tried messing with spanGaps but it only affected null values and i'm trying to not convert to null so the point is still displayed on the chart.

Here's the code:

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('ChartJSTargetID');

  var marksOptions = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 0 // general animation time
      }
    },
    scales: { 
      r: {
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        grid: {
          circular: true,
          color: "#9999A9"
        },
        pointLabels:{
          padding: 35,
          callback: function(label) {
            if (/\s/.test(label)) {
              return label.split(" ");
            }else{
              return label;
            }              
          },
          color: 'black',
          font: {
            size: 11,
            weight: 600
          }
        },
      }

    }
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    const imgWrap = document.getElementById('ChartJSTargetImageID')
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = ctx.toDataURL()
    imgWrap.appendChild(img)
    ctx.style.display = 'none'
  }, 1000);
  
    

  var marksData = {
    labels: ["Conformidade NBR 5410 (BT)","Conformidade NBR 14039 (MT)","Meio Ambiente","Confiabilidade","Operação do sistema","Metodologia de Manutenção do Sistema","Condição dos Equipamentos","Conformidade NR-10","Obsolescência","Informativo"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [10,8,0,2.5,10,0,6.25,6.66666667,7.12418301,10],
      fill:false,
      spanGaps: true,
      borderColor: "#4D217A"
    }]
  };
    
      
  var radarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    plugins: [{
      afterLayout: chart => {
        chart.getDatasetMeta(0).rScale._pointLabelItems.forEach(o => o.textAlign = 'center');      
      }
    }],
    data: marksData,
    options: marksOptions
  });
```

[Radar Chart from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UET2B.png)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are expecting. There are two points with the same style at exactly the same position, they naturally overlap completely. The tooltip shows two values `Meio Ambiente - 0 and 0`, and if you change the style of the second point, you may even see there are two ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w76q4ad0/)).

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any updates on this? Did you find a way to resolve the issue?